# inserting a div between divs using knockout

Tags: knockout.js

Im using knockout and i want to insert / show a div between 2 divs.  Basically im creating an employee details page.  The employees will be listed and when a user clicks on the employee i want his / her details to show under the employee

```
<div>user 1</div>
<div>user 2</div>
<div>user 3</div>
```

clicked

```
<div>user 1</div>
<div>User Details etc</div>
<div>user 2</div>
<div>user 3</div>
```

Im storing the selected user in an editable property which is populated when an employee is clicked and using a with binding i can get the user to come up after all the users, but i would really like to get the details to come up under the relevant employee.  Any ideas?

[Heres a link to quick fiddle ive done](http://jsfiddle.net/ricobano/XwcK9/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

KnockoutJS doesn't manipulate DOM this way. You could use jquery or native js document.createElement('User Details etc') and append it between users divs. The closest to this behavior in knockout is `IF` binding. Explained at the end. Still it needs to be there defined at first, and then knockout can control it.

For knockout way you can start with visibility:

```
<div>user 1</div>
<div data-bind="visible: selectedUser() == user1">User 1 Details etc</div>
<div>user 2</div>
<div data-bind="visible: selectedUser() == user2">User 2 Details etc</div>
<div>user 3</div>
<div data-bind="visible: selectedUser() == user3">User 3 Details etc</div>
```

Or better, in the loop:

```
<!-- ko foreach: users -->
    <div data-bind="text: $data.userName"></div>
    <div data-bind="visible: $parent.selectedUser() == $data.userName, text: $data.userDetails"></div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

If you want to keep those divs out of DOM, change `visibility` to `if`. From knockout website:

> if plays a similar role to the visible binding. The difference is
>   that, with visible, the contained markup always remains in the DOM and
>   always has its data-bind attributes applied - the visible binding just
>   uses CSS to toggle the container element’s visibility. The if binding,
>   however, physically adds or removes the contained markup in your DOM,
>   and only applies bindings to descendants if the expression is true.

You can read more in documentation: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/if-binding.html

Edit: and your modified JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XwcK9/1/